# How to fix SQL Inject Me test results

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, sql-injection

I was asked to look over some classic ASP code, which is fine. But the issue being run into is that he is testing for SQL Injection vulnerability with a FireFox plugin called Sql Inject Me (SIM).
Its getting 306 errors for injection. He wants to be able to run it and not get those errors.

I am starting off with..

```
function scrub() {
        var oldLastname = document.getElementById("Jobtitle").value;

        var newLastName = oldLastname.replace(";", " ").replace("="," ").replace(' " " ', " ").replace("'"," ");
    }
```

and that would be fired on the Submit button click. I'm not sure if that will clear out the errors or not

I read on what FireFoxes plugin is doing and that is...

> "The tool works by sending database escape strings through the form fields. It then looks for database error messages that are output into the rendered HTML of the page."

Any good idea's on the best way to approach this before I go further and then finding out there was a simpler way? I did find this link useful until I realized that it was in regards to php and not JavaScript or ASP.
[Looked at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283476/how-to-fix-server-status-code-302-found-by-sql-inject-me-firefox-addon)

Comment: Search and replace is not enough. Change the SQL statements to  [parameterized queries](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Query_Parameterization_Cheat_Sheet) and read OWASP's [SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Comment: @Melioratus, I'm not used to classic ASP. I do have another page that he sent that has a recordset being created for the updating. I'm going to take a look at those parameterized queries. They look similar.

Comment: If you get stuck or need other resources, please ping me in a comment and I'll see if I can point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Melioratus, thanks...I looked over the parameterized queries, but not understanding how to make it work. The objects look like this..objRecordset.Fields("City") = Request("City"). I haven't come across something like this before. I tried removing some characters like ' ; -- but I get the same amount of errors he does, the only difference is that he is getting 302's and I'm getting 404's

Comment: Found another example on stackoverflow showing parameterized sql using   [classic ASP with jScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377249/using-variables-in-classic-asp-parameterized-sql). Because classic asp allows multiple ways to connect to databases, you should add some code examples of the SQL statements to your question so we can find the correct syntax.

Comment: @Melioratus, thanks for the link, I must have a moment of blindness, after looking at the link, I realized I know about parameterized queries, I use them all the time when using ADO.NET. I'm thrown off by the recordset. If I use the parameterized queries then I would need to rewrite whats he has done?  because it looks like its being posted and passing the info to the page that has the recordset and updates like...objRecordset.Update.

Comment: If he is not using parameterized queries then the statements should be updated to prevent SQL injection. Otherwise, the existing code may allow the [complete compromise](https://www.owasp.org/images/9/9d/SQL_Injection_for_Fun_%26_Profit.pdf) of the application, the database, the server and ultimately the network. Can you update your question with example(s) of the `objRecordset.Update` code that is causing the confusion?

Answer (score 0):

Parameterized Query yields rsInvoices RecordSet

```
<%
Dim rsInvoices
Dim rsInvoices_cmd
Dim rsInvoices_numRows

Set rsInvoices_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
rsInvoices_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_connection_STRING
rsInvoices_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM saleman.GetInvoices(?,?)" 
rsInvoices_cmd.CommandType = 1
rsInvoices_cmd.Prepared = true
rsInvoices_cmd.Parameters.Append rsInvoices_cmd.CreateParameter("param1", 135, 1, -1, rsInvoices__MM_day) '' adDBTimeStamp
rsInvoices_cmd.Parameters.Append rsInvoices_cmd.CreateParameter("param2", 200, 1, 255, rsInvoices__MM_plan) '' adVarChar

Set rsInvoices = rsInvoices_cmd.Execute
%>
```

where

```
<%
Dim rsInvoices__MM_day
rsInvoices__MM_day = "1.2.2014"
If (Request("DayOfReport") <> "") Then 
  rsInvoices__MM_day = Request("DayOfReport")
End If
%>
<%
Dim rsInvoices__MM_plan
rsInvoices__MM_plan = "plan"
If (Request("type") <> "") Then 
  rsInvoices__MM_plan = REPLACE(Request("type"),"'","''")
  ''  This excludes '-injection
  ''  U can write function to check for other types of SQL-Inj
  ''  take in mind that ' sign can be coded in some ways 
End If
%>
```

Comment: Nice parameterized query example! I have one caveat part 2. Although simple search & replace functions are common fixes for SQL Injection and Cross Site Scripting vulnerabilities (XSS), maintaining the code becomes problematic when international character sets are added into mix. Explicitly validating & verifying user inputs is safer and allows useful feedback to the user.